# [groovy beta 2] Question regarding catkin, location of binaries and roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin, binaries, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am migrating code and I have a question regarding catkin. With rosmake the binaries where created in the /mypackage/bin folder, now catkins (using catkin_make) creates them in /mypackage/build/devel/lib/package. The, probably foolish, question is how to execute these binaries. When I try "rosrun mypackage" and autocompletion with tab, the new binaries are not shown. Besides, I used a launch file, which also doesn't work because it looks like the binaries are expected in mypackage/bin. Am I missing something?
Cheers,
Oier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50169/%5Bgroovy-beta-2%5D-question-regarding-catkin,-location-of-binaries-and-roslaunch/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do:

```
catkin_make install
```

This will make an install directory with your binaries, libraries, messages, setup.bash, etc that are all in one easy place. Then do:

```
source /path_to_package/package/install/setup.bash
```

This will make everything available to rosrun.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go into the devel folder and run setup.bash. You should be able to rosrun things then.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1